# arcsine transformation validity

Tags: regression, logistic, data-transformation, count-data, percentage

I have count data that I believe will be more meaningful if converted into percentages to facilitate comparison of data, especially as I have many outliers in my count data, in the same manner as this study: http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0084607

I have seen it mentioned that arcsine transformation is asinine and better results are achieved with logistic regression, so am I better to forget transforming my data and use logistic regression?

Comment: Logistic regression is for binary data. Is your count variable a covariate or the outcome?

Comment: the count data is the response variable, so the outcome.